# Gradle task with compile dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I want to generate a text file based on annotations in my java classes per Gradle task.

I found some references like https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2014/09/gradle-goodness-running-groovy-scripts.html:

```
task runScript(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.mrhaki.CurrentDate'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
}
```

but here I have to use an external file, which I don't want.

I tried defining the class in the `build.gradle` file:

```
class MyScript {
  def call() {
    println ":: Vertx version : $io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.VersionCommand.version"
  }
}

task runScript(type: JavaExec) {
  main = 'MyScript'
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

but it can not be resolved:

```
> Task :runScript FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class MyScript
```

I could use some workaround to pass the script as a string in args, like

```
task runGroovyScript(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = configurations.groovyScript
    main = 'groovy.ui.GroovyMain'
    args '-e', "println 'Hello Gradle!'"
}
```

but that would be uber-ugly.

How can I run an inline groovy code in a Gradle task?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement any Groovy code you want inside a `doFirst` or `doLast` closure of a task:

```
task doSomething {
    doFirst {
        // any Groovy code you want
        println ":: Vertx version : $io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.VersionCommand.version"
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you may create a custom task type that implements the desired behavior:

```
class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    def doSomething() {
        println ":: Vertx version : $io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.VersionCommand.version"
    }
}

task doSomething(type: MyTask)
```

Comment: how do I include the project compileClasspath into those tasks?

Comment: Thats not possible. You can't access the project classpath from the `build.gradle` file, but you may define the dependencies on the buildscript classpath.